# Sum() of every transaction per month even if they didn't make a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL server I have 2 tables, Payments and Customers. Payments has every transaction made by a customer. What i want to know is how i get the amount paid for every month, for every customer even if they didn't make a transaction (So i could get 0 as a result aswell).

now i get the result i want with:

```
    SELECT Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, 
    YEAR(Payment.PaymentDate)AS YEARS, MONTH(Payment.PaymentDate) AS MONTHS,  
    SUM(Amount)AS Total 
    FROM Payment
    join Customer
    ON Customer.CustomerId = Payment.CustomerId
    GROUP BY Customer.FirstName, 
    Customer.LastName, MONTH(Payment.PaymentDate), YEAR(Payment.PaymentDate), 
    Payment.CustomerId
    ORDER BY YEARS desc, MONTHS desc
```

This gives me every amount paid from every customer everymonth.

```
 KATIE   ELLIOTT    2006    2   2.99
 DIANNE     SHELTON 2006    2   4.99
 NATALIE    MEYER   2006    2   5.98
 BETH   FRANKLIN    2006    2   2.99
 MIGUEL BETANCOURT  2006    2   3.98
 ALBERTO    HENNING 2006    2   2.99
 BEVERLY    BROOKS  2006    2   2.99
```

But.. some customers had months where they didn't make a transaction. i want those aswell in my results with the amount 0.

any idea how to do this?

Comment: Create a calendar table. outer join with it.

Comment: *What* SQL? SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? [Edit] your post to tag it. I see that you said "SQL server", but that could technically be anything. Did you mean Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join`.  The question is how to get the list of months.  Assuming you have at least one transaction for each month, you can use the existing data:

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, yyyymm.yyyy, yyyymm.mm,  
       SUM(p.Amount)AS Total 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(p.PaymentDate) as yyyy, MONTH(p.PaymentDate) as mm
      FROM Payment p
     ) yyyymm CROSS JOIN
     Customer c LEFT JOIN
     Payment p
     ON c.CustomerId = p.CustomerId AND
        YEAR(p.PaymentDate) = yyyymm.yyyy AND MONTH(p.PaymentDate) = yyyyymm.mm
GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName, yyyymm.yyyy, yyyymm.mm
ORDER BY yyyymm.yyyy desc, yyyymm.mm desc;
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what i needed. i'll look into cross joins to make it clear for myself.

Answer (score -1):

See below example and update accordingly:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Transcation') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tempdb..##Transcation;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Customer') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE tempdb..#Customer;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Customer (
RowNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(256)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #Customer  VALUES(1,'A');
INSERT INTO #Customer  VALUES(2,'B');
INSERT INTO #Customer  VALUES(3,'C');
INSERT INTO #Customer  VALUES(4,'D');
GO

CREATE TABLE #Transcation (
RowNo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CID INT,
[Year] INT,
[Month] INT,
Amount FLOAT
);
GO

INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (1,2017,1,5.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (2,2017,1,4.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (1,2017,2,5.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (2,2017,2,3.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (1,2017,3,5.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (2,2017,3,3.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (1,2017,4,6.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (2,2017,4,7.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (1,2017,5,8.6);
INSERT INTO #Transcation VALUES (2,2017,5,9.6);
GO

SELECT NAME, ISNULL([YEAR],0), ISNULL([Month],0), ISNULL(SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, [YEAR], [Month]),0)
FROM #Customer AS A LEFT JOIN
#Transcation AS B ON A.CID = B.CID
```